# A histogram with individual proportions on one Y-axis and cumulative proportion on another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a solution in [R] to make a chart like I show here (it is made in Excel):
[image]

I can make a histogram using below code:

`ggplot(data=TestData, aes(x=`QP1`)) +  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 0.1, fill = "lightblue", color="black")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(8,10,0.1)) +  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), breaks = seq(0,1,0.05)) + xlab("QP1")`

[image]

but I could not make a secondary axis and a line plot overlaid on the histogram. I found several example on this site asking similar question, but still had difficulty in truly understanding those solutions.

I need help for:

1. Recommended code to achieve cumulative line plot, but appreciate if some guidance is added to explain the mechanism behind working.
2. I want to control bin width nicely and add some statistic like mean/stdev etc on the chart, am not lazy if have to use dplyr or do some additional working.

Thanks.

Edit:
I could achieve what I wanted initially. During further enhancement, such as adding adding data labels is a challenge in this matter:

```
    ggplot(data=TestData, aes(x=QP1, y=after_stat(count / sum(count)))) +
         
  geom_histogram(fill = "darkorange", color="black", binwidth = 0.1) + 
  
  
  stat_bin(aes(y = after_stat(cumsum(count / sum(count)) * 0.5)),
           geom = "line", colour = "dodgerblue",binwidth = 0.1) + 
  
  stat_bin(aes(label =  after_stat(scales::percent(count / sum(count)))),
           geom = "text",colour="blue", binwidth = 0.1,vjust=1)  +
  
  stat_bin(aes(label =  after_stat(scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count)))))),
           geom = "text",colour="blue", binwidth = 0.1, vjust=-4)  +
  
  
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent, breaks = seq(0,5,.1),
    name = "Proportion",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x * 2, 
                        name = "Cumulative Proportion",
                        labels = scales::percent, breaks = seq(0,1,.2)))
```

[image]

Data labels are added well and show correct numbers, cumulative labels need to be positioned as per sec.axis, how to do that? if we transform by add/div, label value changed not the position. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of things about secondary axes:

1. You must transform input data yourself to fit it on the primary axis.
2. You must give the inverse transform to the `trans` argument of the secondary axis.

In the code below we achieve (1) by doing `y = after_stat(cumsum(count / sum(count)) * 0.1`. The `after_stat()` part replaces the older syntax of `..variable..`. The `cumsum()` calculates the cumulative sum of the proportions, giving the cumulative proportions. The `* 0.1` is dividing the cumulative data by 10 to achieve (1). Then, to achieve (2) you should give the secondary axis `~ .x * 10` to scale up the  number on the axis itself. You can change these scaling factors depending on the plot, but be sure to change them at both places.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
                 fill = "darkorange")  +
  stat_bin(aes(y = after_stat(cumsum(count / sum(count)) * 0.1)),
           geom = "line", colour = "dodgerblue") +
  # Set secondary axis in y scale
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent,
    name = "Proportion",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x * 10, 
                        name = "Cumulative Proportion",
                        labels = scales::percent)
  ) +
  # For pretty colours
  theme(
    axis.line.y.left = element_line(colour = "darkorange"),
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(colour = "darkorange"),
    axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(colour = "darkorange"),
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(colour = "darkorange"),
    axis.line.y.right = element_line(colour = "dodgerblue"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(colour = "dodgerblue"),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(colour = "dodgerblue"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour = "dodgerblue")
  )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT:

With regards to `sec_axis(~ .x * 10, ...)`, this is called 'lambda syntax' where you create a one-sided formula (only right hand side is defined), that will be converted to a function by `rlang::as_function()`. The `.x` is a placeholder for the input data, so the `~ .x * 10` can be read as `function(x) {x * 10}`. This does not work in general, but many tidyverse packages accept this notation at various points.

The `after_stat()` function is the newer notations of `..variable..`, such that `after_stat(count/sum(count))` is the same as `(..count..) / sum(..count..)` you use in your example. The difference is that you don't need to wrap every variable in `..`'s and it is generally more flexible. The `after_stat()` function causes whatever is inside that function to be evaluated after the stat layer has computed the stats. The `count` variable is not an aesthetic you define, it is a computed variable that the stat layer produces, so we need `after_stat()` to do something with that variable.

Comment: Thanks. Such a crisp solution and so quick. Can you please explain more 'sec_axis(~ .x * 10, name = "Cumulative Proportion")' and after_stat function in reference of my question. Also, I want to make sec axis in % format.

Comment: I updated the code example to make percentage signs in the secondary axes and added some explanation at the end.

Comment: Your solution could solver my original question completely (can control both y axis well now), as an addition I wanted to add labels, but it is interfering with the existing scales badly. 'stat_bin(aes(label =  scales::percent(after_stat(count / sum(count)))),
           geom = "text",colour="red", binwidth = 0.1)'

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of `scales::percent()` and `after_stat()` so that the percent is inside the after stat? Also is the binwidth the same as in the other geoms?

Comment: Changing position helped. Binwidth was same for all other geoms. Perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: I edited the question showing final output and with a minor query here only and avoided asking a new question. This will make this question and solution complete.

Comment: Can you add the code to do the text labels to your question? It's hard to figure out how to adapt without seeing the code.

Comment: I have added final code in my Edit in the question above.

Comment: The geom text is almost fine, you'd just also need to declare the `y` aesthetic in the same way as you did for the line / histogram.

Comment: Did it. Thanks a lot! More clear the concepts of how to deal dual axis charts...

Comment: Why do you divide by 10 ?

Comment: Ok, you divide by 10 because the second axis is 10 times the first (100/10)